# How to get multilingual sites after Wikidata reconciliation in OpenRefine

Tags: wikidata, openrefine, reconciliation

I have a column of reconciled entities in OpenRefine which include entities like [Q56085233](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q56085233) and I would like to retrieve all links inside "Multilingual sites", if possible with a separator or only one at a time.
That is Q56085233, for instance, has two pages, one from "commons" (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikimedia_Tamazight) and the other one from "meta" (https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedians_of_Tamazight_User_Group).

Is there a way to retrieve both websites from the "Add column from reconciled values" function? Moreover, is it possible to first call only "meta" pages, and then only "commons" pages?

Answer (score 2):

The Wikidata reconciliation service supports special "properties" to fetch such things, as documented at https://wikidata.reconci.link/ (look for "special properties" there).

The links inside the "Multilingual sites" are called "sitelinks". For `meta.wikimedia.org` they can be fetched by using the `Smetawiki` code in the "Add columns from reconciled values" dialog. You could similarly fetch sitelinks for other Wikimedia sites (`Sitwiki` for the Italian Wikipedia, for instance).